# RabbitMQ Camel - bean is blocked

Tags: java

Consume from rabbitmq -> bean to handle message -> reply message.
I'm facing issue: when bean is pending to process, it's blocked and done receive new message to handle.
Only when bean is finish then reply message to reply queue, It able to receive new message
My code:

```
from("rabbitmq:adapter?queue=bvb-adapter&routingKey=bvb-adapter-route")
                .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson, CoreTransaction.class)
                .bean("initTransactionHandler", "handle")
                .marshal()
                .json(JsonLibrary.Gson, CoreTransaction.class);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly, 
First service send message to rabbitmq then wait reply message.
Second service receive this message then pass to a bean to handle.
In this bean, I call extarnel api in seconds, meanwhile, I push message to rabbitmq and I see that second service cannot receive this message until the bean finished.